# How to get these ion-tabs to appear correctly in the context of an ion-nav-bar?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get a tabbed layout, as I have outlined below to appear correctly:

```
Copied from: http://codepen.io/imee12/pen/YPOGJe

<ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons" >
    <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
        <ion-tab title="Tab 1" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
            <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
                <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Tab 2" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
            <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
                <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Tab 3" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
            <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
                <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

The tabs exist inside the following container, which has an `ion-nav-bar`.

```
<ion-side-menus>

    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
            <div class="title">Side Menu</div>
        </header>
        <ion-content class="has-header" has-header="true">
            <ul class="list">
                <a ui-sref="entry" class="item">Back To Entry Page</a>
                <a ui-sref="main.home" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Home</a>
                <a ui-sref="main.tabs" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Tabs</a>
            </ul>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

The Codepen project is referencing version 0.9.27 of the ionic bundle & css, e.g.

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I've recently updated my local environment to the ionic nightly build, so I'm currently on

```
 * Ionic, v1.2.4-nightly-1917 //both js & css
```

And now the tabbed page is appearing as (note the text "Tab 1 Content" is being overlapped by the ion-nav-bar)

[image]

I should also note I've applied the `class="has-header"` to both the side menu and the tabs. The side menu appears correctly, but the tabs don't.

[image]

Is there a different way that I need to display the tabs in the context of the updated ionic bundle and css, so that it appears as follows?

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the resolution was to put the tabs inside an `ion-content` container with `class="has-header"`.

```
<ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">
    <!-- the ion-content container -->
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
        <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
            <ion-tab title="Tab 1" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
                <ion-content padding="true">
                    <h2 class="has-header">Tab 1 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Tab 2" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
                <ion-content padding="true">
                    <h2 class="has-header">Tab 2 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Tab 3" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
                <ion-content padding="true">
                    <h2 class="has-header">Tab 3 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also, to get the pesky tabs to stick to the bottom, I brought `$ionicConfigProvider` into the angular config and gave it a slap with the position stick.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'services'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ionicConfigProvider', 
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) { 

            $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // other values: top
```